# Drawing a two variable plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm new to python trying to find out the best way to plot y axes value vs two variables with multiple options my table example is below:

```
    Class   Group   aa      bb      cc
    aaaa    0       3783    229378  229765
    aaaa    1       488589  209433  210478
    aaaa    0       462676  222555  227456
    aaaa    1       407283  299622  303896
    bbbb    0       413483  291949  295685
    bbbb    1       418406  176578  178028
    cccc    0       390063  185829  186766
    cccc    1       428003  203538  201961
    cccc    2       369612  206001  204564
    ......
```

I'm trying to plot aa,bb,cc (y-axes) on the x-axes class and groups. Was thinking a boxplot or histogram? Doesn't matter if the hue is Class or Groups.
Thank you for your help.

Kevin

Comment: matplotlib has a [great gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) of example plots, and it should be your first stop if you don't know what type of plot you want. There are multiple ways to plot your data, each of which highlights different aspects of the data, and you're basically asking us to guess which you want the most. Instead, please choose from the gallery, try it with your data, and return with a question if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This is more like a data-visualization question compared to a python/matplotlib/seaborn question.

Since you are plotting numerical variables against categorical variables, you might take a look at [plotting with categorical data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html). A box-plot would well serve your purpose, although recently there has been some critiques over box plot for [missing distribution-related information](https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/boxplot.html). Personally, I would go with a [violin plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot).

There are a good amount of resource you can find at [From Data to Viz](https://www.data-to-viz.com/) and [The Python Graph Gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/) about choice of plot types when visually presenting your data.